# strange behaviour: hibernate 3 inverted column values on generated sql. ManyToMany JPA

Tags: hibernate, many-to-many

Having,

```
class RadicadoOficio {
    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name="cor_radicado_localidad", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="ano_radicado"), @JoinColumn(name="num_radicado")}, inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="interno_localidad")})
private List<Localidad> localidades;
}

class Localidad {// does not reference RadicadoOficio. unidirectional relationship }
```

asume ano_radicado is an int (ano somewhat means year) and num is a string (actually is a "number" that can contain letters)

generates sql: 
    delete from cor_radicado_localidad where ano_radicado=2012 and num_radicado=AX33

that's a good thing.

However if you change the order of the joinColumns in RadicadoOficio, i.e:

```
joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="num_radicado"), @JoinColumn(name="ano_radicado")},
```

you get: 
    delete from cor_radicado_localidad where ano_radicado=AX33 and num_radicado=2012

that's bad.

As far as I know, the order of the joincolumns in the mapping shouldn´t matter, and the generated SQL should be the same in both cases. M i missing something? tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of join columns in the mapping doesn't matter **if** it's followed by the *referencedColumnName* parameter. Meaning that if you implicitly specify which column in join table references which column on the other tables you wont have any problem.

So consider changing your annotations as follows:

```
@JoinTable(name="cor_radicado_localidad", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="ano_radicado" ,referencedColumnName="ano_radicado" ), @JoinColumn(name="num_radicado",referencedColumnName="num_radicado")}, inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="interno_localidad")})
```

Your first example was running *good* only by an accident. Simply because the order of columns **ano_radicado** and **num_radicado** were the same in **Radicado** table.

Hibernate is not smart enough to distinguish between column names and their corresponding reference column in other tables,in other words,this is practically impossible since you may use some different names in the join table. Look at this example:

```
Table foo
firstId  :(int)
secondId :(int)

Table bar
firstId :(int)

Table foo_bar
foo_secondId :(int)
foo_firstId :(int)
bar_firstId :(int)
```